# How can you get input from a physical keyboard in react-native without using <TextInput>?

Tags: react-native

In React Native with a 'TextInput', you can use 'onChangeText' to get the keyboard input from both onscreen keyboards as well as from a physical keyboard connected to the mobile.

My problem is:
How can you get input from a physical keyboard without using 'TextInput'?

Like below script can be used in browsers to listen when a key is pressed & it works without embedding it in a 'div' or an 'input' tag.

```
<script>
onkeydown=(e)=>console.log(e)
</script>
```

Thanks, for your help.